# which method to implement exp function in c?

Tags: c, math, exp

I want to calculate the error of exp function under finite precision(data type is double). Is taylor series or other special algorithm?

Comment: Your title says you want to implement the `exp` function. Your body says you want to calculate the error of the `exp` function. (a) Which is correct? (b) If you want to calculate the error, from which implementation do you want to calculate the error? For example, do you want to know how much the results calculated by `exp` in your C implementation differ from the mathematically ideal e**x function?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think we must know the method implement the exp function first, then can calculate the error. You are right. I want to know the error calculated by exp differ from the ideal.

Comment: The implementation from fdlibm uses a rational approximation and has error less than 1 ulp http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_exp.c

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generally, the best way to implement e<sup>*x*</sup> is by calling the `exp` function provided by your computing platform.

Failing this, implementing the `exp` function is complicated and requires several esoteric skills. An implementation typically involves:

- Testing the input for various special cases, such as NaNs.
- Multiplying the input by a specially prepared representation of log<sub>2</sub>e, to transform the problem from e<sup>*x*</sup> to 2<sup>*y*</sup>, where *y* = *x* • log<sub>2</sub>e.
- Moving the integer part of *y* into the exponent field of a floating-point encoding.
- Evaluating the exponential of the fractional part of *y* with a [minimax polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_polynomial).
- Combining the two results above.

Additionally:

- The minimax polynomial is engineered, often with special software, using the [Remez algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm) or something similar.
- The work must be done with some extended precision so that the final result can be calculated precisely.

Taylor series are inappropriate for evaluating functions because they are inaccurate away from their center points. This means they take too many terms to converge to the necessary precision. Having too many terms not only takes time but also makes it difficult to do the arithmetic accurately.

Comment: I found this method in wiki, but i cant't confirm. Tks.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with much of what Eric said in his response, there are a few points worth adding. I wrote a tool that, among other things, allows evaluation of the exponential to high (user specified) precision.

When the precision can vary, one MUST resort to tools like series approximations, since then no single polynomial approximation will suffice. Even so, there are many tricks one can employ. In fact, I was surprised by the variety of tricks I used to accelerate such a series.

A good starter reference for any such endeavor is that by Hart, "Computer Approximations", a book that is sadly not easy to find. It offers many polynomial approximations, but also talks in moderate detail about range reduction tricks.

The exponential series is itself especially interesting. I describe the methods I employed for the exponential in section 4.1 of the file HPFMod2.pdf, which is included with [HPF](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class).

As an example, to compute exp(123.456789), one might try to use a series directly, but better is to store the value of e itself. Then we can use a range reduction to compute

```
exp(123.456789) = exp(1)*exp(2)*exp(8)*exp(16)*exp(32)*exp(64)*exp(.456789)
```

We get the exponentials of powers of 2 by repeated squaring, then the fractional part will converge moderately rapidly. (E.g., 31 terms are needed for 100 digits of precision in the final series.)

However, suppose we just happened to notice that

```
123.456789 = 28*ln(10) + 58.9844063961667
```

Now, we could write the desired exponential as:

```
exp(123.456789) = 10^28 * exp(1)*exp(2)*exp(8)*exp(16)*exp(32)*exp(-0.0155936038332811)
```

As long as we know (having stored it) the value of ln(10), the final series will require only about 17 terms to achieve a desired 100 digits of precision.