# How can I write a function to compute a^b when b could be negative or fractional?

Tags: c, algorithm, function, math, exponent

I want to make a exponent function that allows fractions and negatives. I have seen related questions but haven't really found what I'm looking for. I need a function that will be able to do something like this `pow(5,1/2)` and `pow(7,-2)`. Is there anyone that can help me?

Comment: Note that, in C, `1/2` equals 0, so `pow(5, 1/2)` will be `pow(5, 0)`, which is 1. Consider using 1.0f/2 instead

Comment: for negative powers -- you can just do  `1/pow(7,2)`

Comment: Have you tried [`pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow)?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth- I think the question is how to write a function like this from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability to compute e<sup>x</sup> and ln x, then you can use the following identity to compute a<sup>b</sup>:

> a<sup>b</sup> = e<sup>b ln a</sup>

It looks like the x86 architecture has native support for computing logarithms; if you look at [the x86 instruction listings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings), the `FYL2X` instruction can compute logs.  You can probably approximate e<sup>x</sup> using the Taylor series:

> e<sup>x</sup> = 1 + x + x<sup>2</sup> / 2! + x<sup>3</sup> / 3! + x<sup>4</sup> / 4! + ...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good implementations of math library routines use minimax polynomials or something similar, not Taylor series. Taylor series converge too slowly and have poor error properties.

Comment: @EricPostpischil- Can you post a link to something about that?  I'm aware Taylor series aren't the best option, but I haven't heard about minimax polynomials.

Comment: Start with Wikipedia for background and introduction. There are links in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15351205/298225). I also recommend [Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Floating-Point-Arithmetic-Jean-Michel-Muller/dp/081764704X).

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to implement `pow` from scratch, then you might want to use Taylor's series.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Comment: Good implementations of math library routines use minimax polynomials or something similar, not Taylor series. Taylor series converge too slowly and have poor error properties.